# Listening iBeacons even if the app is closed

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I was wondering if it is possible to listen ibeacons even if the app that have the implementation (code to interact over BLE - ibeacons) is closed.

Is it possible? Can i write a code that 'tells' to the device to listen ibeacons all the time and if found any, need to do some action based on code from specific app? Or i need that my app still running all the time to listen the ibeacons?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) is designed to do exactly this.  It automatically launches a background beacon scanner service on various system events, and can then start your app's Activities based on beacon detections.

See here for details: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html

Comment: first of all, thanks for this library. It saved my day :) ... good to know..but if i close the app, those background scanner will still working?

Comment: Yes, if you use the RegionBootstrap class as described in the link.

Comment: Works, but when close the app not detect anymore.  I'm testing in android 5.1