# Can I scan for iBeacons with Play Services 9.2?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-nearby

In the 9.2 Release Notes of Google Play services I found the following:

> Nearby
>
> This release removes the requirement that clients use the Proximity Beacon API to manage their beacons. Nearby will now return parsed BLE advertisements directly, allowing clients to use their own solution to interpret those advertisements.

That sounds to me, as if I should be able to subscribe to Nearby Messages with Strategy.BLE_ONLY and get information about BLE beacons (which includes iBeacons) in the vicinity without "owning"/registering the beacons vie Proximity Beacon API.

Do I understand that correctly? Does anyone have a helpful link to a sample or other resources that might help implementing this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe with a MessageFilter that uses [includeIBeaconIds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/MessageFilter.Builder.html#includeIBeaconIds(java.util.UUID,%20java.lang.Short,%20java.lang.Short)).

The code would look something like:

```
MessageFilter filter = new MessageFilter.Builder()
    .includeIBeaconIds(MY_IBEACON_PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null)
    .build();
SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
    .setFilter(filter)
    .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
    .build();
MessageListener listener = new MessageListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFound(Message message) {
    IBeaconId beaconId = IBeaconId.from(message);
    Log.i("Test", "Saw iBeacon " + beaconId);
  }
};
Nearby.Messages.subscribe(apiClient, messageListener, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code. Is it also possible to scan for "all iBeacons" not just `MY_IBEACON_PORXIMITY_UUID`? Would I just leave the call to `includeIBeaconIds` out or is there some magic value to for `MY_IBEACON_PORXIMITY_UUID` that will return all beaconIds?

Comment: it would be great, if you could share some insights into "scanning for all nearby beacon ids". Thx

Comment: Not currently possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Does anyone have a helpful link to a sample or other resources that might help implementing this feature?**

Listening to iBeacon from an Android device is possible as confirmed in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923110/listening-ibeacons-even-if-the-app-is-closed) and [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007291/how-to-detect-ibeacon-in-android).
You can make use of the [AltBeacon/android-beacon-library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library).

> It allows Android devices to use beacons much like iOS devices do. An
>   app can request to get notifications when one or more beacons appear
>   or disappear. An app can also request to get a ranging update from one
>   or more beacons at a frequency of approximately 1Hz.

Don't forget to read about [Getting Beacon Messages](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages#parse_beacon_messages) from the Google Docs too.

Here's a snippet when subscribing in the foreground:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.d(TAG, "Found message: " + messageAsString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.d(TAG, "Lost sight of message: " + messageAsString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be ~the code you'd use to retrieve a message attachment from e.g. an Eddystone beacon. It's missing the critical part where you actually subscribe though as shown in the sample it was copied from (https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages).

Comment: @noogui, thanks for your answer. We are already using AltBeacon and are evaluating to migrate to Nearby Messages. The documentation you referenced is aimed at retrieving message attachements (as brian-duff already mentioned).

Comment: @FlorianBarth I think Brian has the say in this since he's working on Nearby project at Google. I'm just quoting what I found from the docs.

Comment: Thx for clarifying and for your help, @noogui

Comment: AltBeacon is the only option?  What about Play Service beacon support?